# Dent below seat stay on a steel frame safe to ride?

Tags: frames, damage

This is a Surly Krampus frame; I just noticed this small dent while cleaning.  It was purchased brand new, I've had it for about 2 weeks.  Should I be worried?

[image: Photo of a bicycle tube, with a small dent circled.]

Comment: It honestly might just be a paint defect too.

Comment: This demonstrates the usefulness of regular cleaning as it lets us discover potential defects, minor or major.

Comment: On a standard steel frame such a dent is hardly worth mentioning.

Comment: I think we need a canonical question and answer for dent judgement type questions.

Answer (score 12):

No, you should not be worried. A dent of that size is probably not a concern on all but the very lightest (and thinnest walled) steel tubing. Surly are economical bikes and use relatively heavy and thick-walled steel.

It’s my understanding that framebuilders can roll out dents larger than this, but not so large enough to warrant replacing the whole tube.

Comment: *Yes, safe to ride. No, shouldn’t be worried.

Comment: Thank you guys!